# Letters group Games-Howell post hoc in R

Tags: r, posthoc

I use the `sweetpotato database` included in `library agricolae` of R:

> data(sweetpotato)
>   This dataset contains two variables: yield(continous variable) and virus(factor variable).

Due to Levene test is significant I cannot assume homogeneity of variances and I apply Welch test in R instead of one-way  ANOVA followed by Tukey posthoc.

Nevertheless, the problems come from when I apply posthoc test. In Tukey posthoc test I use `library(agricolae)` and displays me the superscript letters between virus groups. Therefore there are no problems.

Nevertheless, to perform Games-Howell posthoc, I use `library(userfriendlyscience)` and I obtain Games-Howell output but it's impossible for me to obtain a letter superscript comparison between virus groups as it is obtained through `library(agricolae)`.

The code used it was the following:

> library(userfriendlyscience)
>
> data(sweetpotato)
>
> oneway<-oneway(sweetpotato$virus, y=sweetpotato$yield, posthoc =
>   'games-howell')
>
> oneway

I try with `cld()` importing previously `library(multcompView)` but doesn't work.

Can somebody could helps me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality does not exist in `userfriendlyscience` at the moment. You can see which means differ, and with which p-values, by looking at the row names of the dataframe with the post-hoc test results. I'm not sure which package contains the `sweetpotato` dataset, but using the `ChickWeight` dataset that comes with R (and is used on the `oneway` manual page):

```
oneway(y=ChickWeight$weight, x=ChickWeight$Diet, posthoc='games-howell');
```

Yields:

```
### (First bit removed as it's not relevant.)

### Post hoc test: games-howell

     diff  ci.lo ci.hi    t     df     p
2-1 19.97   0.36 39.58 2.64 201.38  .044
3-1 40.30  17.54 63.07 4.59 175.92 <.001
4-1 32.62  13.45 51.78 4.41 203.16 <.001
3-2 20.33  -6.20 46.87 1.98 229.94  .197
4-2 12.65 -10.91 36.20 1.39 235.88  .507
4-3 -7.69 -33.90 18.52 0.76 226.16  .873
```

The first three rows compare groups 2, 3 and 4 to 1: using alpha = .05, 1 and 2 have the same means, but 3 and 4 are higher. This allows you to compute the logical vector you need for `multCompLetters` in `multcompView`. Based on the example from the manual page at `?multcompView`:

```
### Run oneway anova and store result in object 'res'
res <- oneway(y=ChickWeight$weight, x=ChickWeight$Diet, posthoc='games-howell');

### Extract dataframe with post hoc test results,
### and overwrite object 'res'
res <- res$intermediate$posthoc;

### Extract p-values and comparison 'names'
pValues <- res$p;

### Create logical vector, assuming alpha of .05
dif3 <- pValues > .05;

### Assign names (row names of post hoc test dataframe)
names(dif3) <- row.names(res);

### convert this vector to the letters to compare
### the group means (see `?multcompView` for the
### references for the algorithm):
multcompLetters(dif3);
```

This yields as final result:

```
    2     3     4     1 
  "a"   "b"   "c" "abc"
```

This is what you need, right?

I added this functionality to `userfriendlyscience`, but it will be a while before this new version will be on CRAN. In the meantime, you can get the source code for this update at https://github.com/Matherion/userfriendlyscience/blob/master/R/oneway.R if you want (press the 'raw' button to get an easy-to-download version of the source code).

Note that if you need this updated version, you need to set parameter `posthocLetters` to `TRUE`, because it's `FALSE` by default. For example:

```
oneway(y=ChickWeight$weight,
       x=ChickWeight$Diet,
       posthoc='games-howell',
       posthocLetters=TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Matherion!

Comment: If this answers your question, you can accept it as answer. Which then increases our reputation scores (mine more than yours, of course :-P).

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be
`dif3 <- pValues < .05`, instead of `dif3 <- pValues > .05` ?

This way the letters are the same if the distributions are 'the same' (this is, no evidence that they are different).

Please correct me if I'm interpreting this wrong.